# Using AWS, how to ssh to k8s nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, kubernetes

The quickstart mentions a few times that, "You should be able to ssh into any node in your cluster ..." (e.g., http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/connecting-applications.html#environment-variables). I have tried as described below but I am getting timed out.

1. I used `export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash` to start the cluster
2. I have only specified AWS_REGION in my environment
3. The nodes are residing in VPC and I am able to ping them from a bastion

This is the result:

`ubuntu@ip-10-128-1-26:~$ ssh core@170.20.0.248 -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 170.20.0.248 [170.20.0.248] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 170.20.0.248 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 170.20.0.248 port 22: Connection timed out
ubuntu@ip-10-128-1-26:~$`

Any idea or pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have ssh open to whatever box you're trying to connect from in security groups?

Comment: Yes, @Eli, both on the bastion box and the minion.

Comment: You're trying to connect to the internal VPC address of the box. Did you assign them external IPs as well? Can you connect to those? Also, which addresses of the bastion and minion did you allow access to through security groups? You'll have to make sure it's their internal addresses or their security group if you're trying to connect internally. All in all, the timeout looks a lot like a security group issue, so I'm really guessing it's something there.

Comment: Thanks, @Eli. It is really the security group. Then, would you please tell me which key I should use for ssh? I have tried ~/.ssh/kube_aws_rsa but it didn't work. Since the minion uses this image: ubuntu-vivid-15.04-amd64-server-20150611 and so I tried `ssh -l ./.ssh/kube_aws_rsa ubuntu@the_ip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is with making sure the corresponding security group is open to ssh from whichever nodes you'd like to connect from. Make sure it's open to the public IP or the private IP, depending on which you're connecting from. For the right ssh key to use: it'll be whichever one you setup when spinning up the nodes. You can check that in the EC2 pane of AWS in the "key pairs" side bar option:

[image: AWS key pairs image]

Comment: Thanks, @Eli. I can reach the instance now by doing telnet with port 22; however, I am still not able to ssh to it with the kube_aws_rsa key:  telnet 52.33.250.80 22
Trying 52.33.250.80...
Connected to ec2-52-33-250-80.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
^]
telnet> quit
$ ssh -l ~/.ssh/kube_aws_rsa ubuntu@52.33.250.80
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Verify that's the correct key you created the boxes with, and verify that's the correct username to connect to the boxes with. This guide should help: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html